# MySQLi , declare variable and using math to count a median

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to do some math in this SQL query. I'm not used to this syntax. Trying to count a median for line 3 in the query.

**-?-** = Can I put a variable here?

**-??-** = Can I make this line a variable some how?

This is the code I have done:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])):


$sql_art_sum = "SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM post WHERE user_id = ?), **-?-**
                (SELECT count(*) FROM comment),
                (SELECT count(*)/ **-??-** FROM comment)";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_art_sum)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($art_sum, $comment_sum, $comment_median);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating new variables in mysql you need to use 'AS' so for example:

```
SELECT x, y, 
       (SELECT SUM(x) - sum(y)
        FROM tablename
        WHERE b <= c
       ) as z
FROM  tablename
```

Hope this is the answer you are searching for